# Which MechWarrior games will still run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mechwarrior

I'm thinking about going to Windows 7 from XP.  Has anyone run any of the MechWarrior titles on 7?

Comment: Which ones? Activision, MS, all? :)

Comment: ALL! LoL. Back to Cresent Hawk if someone knows.

Comment: I run Crescent Hawk's Inception/Revenge every now and then, using DOSBox...

Comment: And of course, there's Mechwarrior online now... http://mwomercs.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the very least I know I have run mechwarrior 4 on windows 7...and it is now free!

http://mtxgear.mektek.net/MW4/

Comment: Any idea on MW3?

Comment: I can't verify this myself, but I have heard of MW3 running on windows 7 as long as the compatibility mode is set to win 98/ME.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both MW4 and MW3 and their expansions will run on Win7. Just make sure your comp modes are set correctly.

Comment: What compatibility modes did you have success with?